# Can't Access The Dashboard Functions

Tags: dashboard

I just changed the theme of my website https://stammer.in but after changing the theme some functions from my Dashboard are missing. I can only Acess Post, Media, Pages, Comments, Events, Profile, Tools and WPBakery Page Builder. I can't access to other functions like appearance, settings etc. Nor I can access to the visual composer to which I can access earlier. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. have a look at this, cause that seems to have changed for ur user with ur modifications: [https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#:~:text=WordPress%20has%20six%20pre-defined,“%2C%20and%20“edit_users“](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#:%7E:text=WordPress%20has%20six%20pre-defined,%E2%80%9C%2C%20and%20%E2%80%9Cedit_users%E2%80%9C).
2. would be better to tell us which theme modifications u made, otherwise it's impossible to tell why what happened!